# Permission Denied Error in Visual Studio Code on Chromebook

Tags: bash, chrome-book, chrome-os, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding and trying to run my first line of code in Visual Studio Code. However, I keep getting the error message `bash: permission denied` and can't proceed. I am using a Chromebook and have configured it to work with Visual Studio Code. Could this error be due to the operating system or something else?